# How can you start a switch statement over again if an incorrect input is entered

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibraryTester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int userOption = Menu(sc);
        switch (userOption){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter Book ID"); break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please enter Book details"); break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please enter the first word of the book you wish to delete"); break;


        default: System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-6"); break;
// i'm not sure how to print the menu again


        public static int Menu(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Please choose a number from the following options");
        System.out.println("1. Add a Book");
        System.out.println("2. Edit a Books details");
        System.out.println("3. Delete a Book");
        System.out.println("4. Loan a Book");
        System.out.println("5. Return a Book");
        System.out.println("6. Exit the program");
        int userOption = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        return userOption;

//this is only a small part of my code


            }
}
```

Comment: Put it in a loop...?

Comment: You should generally add a language tag (one exception would be a pure algorithm question). I have added the `Java` tag for you.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want the *switch* statement to restart, it would end up in the same case-block once more and keep repeating. Most likely you want the code *before* the switch-statement to repeat as well, no?

Comment: Sorry guys I've only just started to learn Java or any programming for that matter. I need the Menu I have created to appear in the scanner again if the user does not input a correct option/case

Answer (score 1):

The common solution to a problem like this is to wrap the switch statement in a [`do..while` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).  At the end of the loop, if you haven't gotten a valid answer, your loop would simply repeat, and the first thing it would do is to reprint your menu.  It would look something like this:

```
bool needAnswer = true;
do {
    int userOption = Menu(sc);
    ... // set needAnswer=false if you're happy with their result.
} while (needAnswer);
```